# Browser settings to enable Open,Save,Save As dialogue box

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

When i double click on a hyperlink in IE11 or Chrome browser,it's forcing me to save the file rather opening Open,Save,Save As dialogue box

What changes do i make in browser settings to enable Open,Save,Save As dialogue box?

Thanks in advance 
Libin Sebastian